# Undergraduate reference on conditional probability and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, conditional-probability

I would like to know if there is a reference regarding the concepts of conditional probability and conditional expectation at the undergraduate level for a statistics student that is more comprehensive than the exposition in Sheldon Ross's book 'A First Course in Probability,' but not advanced in terms of measure theory

Comment: Do you want no measure theory at all or just no advanced measure theory?

Comment: No measure theory at all, that is, the same background as the Sheldon Ross Book

Comment: grimmett and stirzaker, probability and random processes